# How to create multiple version of one entity using hibernate xml?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one entity, customer for example, this entity is mapped with table. So, this entity is used in different places of application. In each case we need different sets of fields. Some data to display it on view, some service data (different flags and statuses for example) and sometimes all data stored in database. For now I do it like

```
<class name="Customer" table="customer" entity-name="CustomerFull">
<id name="id">
<property name="property 1"
<property name="property 2"
<property name="property 3"
<property name="property 4"
...

<class name="Customer" table="customer" entity-name="CustomerLight">
<id name="id">
<property name="property 1"
<property name="property 2"
...

<class name="Customer" table="customer" entity-name="OneMoreCustomer">
<id name="id">
<property name="property 3"
<property name="property 4"
...
```

Is it correct way to solve my task like this?

Comment: Yes, you are saying to your mapping that the object `CustomerLight` has that references in the table. When hibernate read the mapping, he ignore if the table that you are referencing has more columns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible, You have to add these code in your hibernate.xml file where you are mapping models or hbm files, in this technique we don't have to create any extra files for models or hbm we can add all entities in single hibernate file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Employee" table="employee">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id"/>
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="name"/>
    </property>
</class>

<class name="Address" table="address">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id"/>
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="address"></column>
    </property>
</class></hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: I'm didn't understood anything from your reply, really. "Yes, it`s possible", next you post code that absolutely didn't helps. As I see your code describes absolutely different situation. There are 2 entities mapped to 2 different tables, and how it might helps me when I need mapping same Entity multiple times, how it relates to my problem?

Comment: #snowhead dear you have to head these code in hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file where you are mapping your entities or hbm files, there you can add these mapping rather than mapping models